# Preventing execution of a query if a specific parameter is not present in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Using *T-SQL* and *Microsoft SQL Server 2014*, I am attempting to find a way to restrict access to a table if a specific parameter is not present.

I can do this on SQL Server 2016 by creating a function which utilises the `SESSION_CONTEXT()` function and then applying that to my schema.

Since I do not have access to `SESSION_CONTEXT()` in SQL Server 2014, I am unable to get the value of the specified key in the current session context.

Can anybody suggest a solution which would enable me to circumvent the use of SESSION_CONTEXT() for this scenario (or suggest a better solution)

**SQL Server 2016 Compatible T-SQL**

```
CREATE SCHEMA RestrictSchema
GO

CREATE FUNCTION RestrictSchema.DenyWithoutParameter (@Parameter INT)
RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN

SELECT 1 AS VALID_PARAMETER_SUPPLIED
WHERE @Parameter = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'@Parameter') AS INT)
GO

CREATE SECURITY POLICY RestrictSchema.ScehmaParameterRequirementForTableX 

  ADD FILTER PREDICATE RestrictSchema.DenyWithoutParameter (@Parameter) ON dbo.TableX
 ,ADD BLOCK PREDICATE RestrictSchema.DenyWithoutParameter (@Parameter) ON dbo.TableX

GO
```

Comment: Would [context_info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) meet your needs?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to accomplish technically but why are you trying to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in the `RestrictSchema` schema,

- SessionID
- ParameterKey
- ParameterValue
- TimeToLive

Add an entry to it for every session/connection as needed, then rewrite `RestrictSchema.DenyWithoutParameter` to select from there, and occasionally garbage collect.

Comment: Nice approach @dlatikay. I will give it a shot and let you know how I get on.